# Integration of Instamojo with Android?

Tags: android, instamojo

I am new to Android, just doing one requirement like how to integrate instamojo with android application.

I have done the setup like created one account in instamojo got ClientId and Client Secret . Then I have kept my access_token.php file inside my server.

After that instamojo is telling to call callInstamojoPay() from my MainActivity, that I have done it.

But somewhere I have done something wrong, not getting the exact output.

**Coding**

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //learnandgrow.tips Call the function callInstamojo to start payment here

           callInstamojoPay("learnandgrow@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxxx", "20", "official", "buyername");
        }
    });
```

Can anyone give some idea or any suggestions to get some idea regarding this kind of problem ?

Comment: Kindly elaborate your problem. Its difficult to find out the issue your're facing. Please provide error stacktrace if any. or screenshots. thanks

Comment: Thank you Mr @Deepakkaku for your quick response. I got the solution . Problem was there in my Xampp server. As I struggled to find the solution so I have written step by step process to solve this issue, It may help for others . http://www.learnandgrow.tips/integration-instamojo-android/